# Microsoft azure para alojar website?

Tags: microsoft-azure, hospedagem

Surgiu-me uma dúvida, eu tenho um domínio e um alojamento requisitados a uma empresa normal. Ouvi falar de Microsoft Azure que funciona através de *cloud*. Podiam-me explicar melhor como isto funciona para um website?

Se permite ser exatamente igual o site em php e as bases de dados tudo online como num outro alojamento qualquer. E este serviço torna mais rápida a navegação no website e claro existe alguma vantagem econômica?

E se trocar existe possibilidade de usar um domínio registrado noutra empresa? Obrigado pelo ajuda, peço desculpa pela chuva de perguntas mas estou muito curioso acerca deste sistema.

Comment: Pedro, te aconselho a [ler a documentação oficial](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/) disponibilizada pela MS no site do Azure... Se eu não me engano o Azure também aceita sites em PHP. Entre em contato com o pessoal da MS pra saber mais também.

Comment: Só confirmando, suporta PHP sim e [algumas coisas legais a mais](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/15/supercharge-your-php-productivity-on-azure/) =)

Answer (score 3):

O Azure tem algumas opções para o alojamento de websites. As mais comuns são as seguintes:

- **Máquinas virtuais**: a opção de IaaS (*Infrastructure as a Service*) - você basicamente "aluga" um computador que está rodando no cloud, e é responsável por instalar tudo o que é necessário para rodar o seu website. O computador pode estar rodando Windows (várias versões) ou Linux (várias versões). Você tem o total controle sobre a máquina, inclusive sendo responsável por fazer atualizações necessárias.
- **Websites**: a opção de PaaS (*Platform as a Service*) - você faz o upload dos arquivos que formam o seu website, que irão rodar em uma máquina gerenciada pelo Azure. Patches e outros updates são aplicados automaticamente, e você só precisa se preocupar com o website em si. Várias linguagens são suportadas, entre elas PHP (dá uma olhada [nesse tutorial: criar o website](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-create-web-sites/) ou [nesse outro tutorial - mais completo, usando PHP e MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/) para mais informações).

As duas opções acima suportam domínios customizados, mesmo que estejam registrados em outras empresas (há um tempo atrás eu tinha um domínio registrado no GoDaddy.com que apontava para um website do Azure; não lembro como foi a configuração mas não era muito complicado).

Em relação a base de dados, no primeiro caso (máquina virtual) você pode instalar o BD na máquina (ela é "sua", e pode fazer o que quiser com ela). No segundo caso você pode ou usar algum BD no cloud (tanto no Azure quanto fora dele, contanto que você tenha algo tipo um *connection string* que aponte para onde a base de dados está armazenada), ou até mesmo ter uma base de dados local (na sua empresa), e acessá-la via "[conexões híbridas](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started/)".

Em relação à velocidade: provavelmente não vai ter muita diferença em relação a se você tiver o site rodando localmente. A vantagem do Azure (e de outros provedores de Cloud, como o AWS) é que eles têm vários *data centers*, então você pode ter o seu website redundante em vários locais e o cliente acessará o que tiver mais perto, reduzindo a latência das requisições.

Em relação ao preço - você paga o que você usa. Uma máquina virtual vai sair mais caro que um website simples, mas você tem mais controle. Com os websites também há vários modos (desde de gratuitos, com umas quotas relativamente baixas e pior performance, até os pagos que você paga dependendo do tamanho da máquina que está sendo usada e quantas cópias (replicação) estão rodando. Dá uma olhada na [página da calculadora de preço](http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/calculator/) que você pode ter uma ideia de quanto custa.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Se vc estiver pensando no contexto de uma máquina so, então, quase não existem vantagens. Digo quase, pq sempre da para se tirar proveito das ferramentas oferecidas nesses ambientes de cloud, mas, em contra partida, é um ambiente mais caro (proporcionalemente falando).

As vantagens, de ambientes como da Azure, irão aparecer em casos onde vc comece a necessitar de escalar o seu site.

Um exemplo seria o caso de vc ter uma máquina que rodará 100% do tempo (24 h/d e 7 d/s). E pode alugar outra máquina que só vai estar ligada em horários de pico.

Pq alguém vai querer isso? Pq não uma máquina só e mais "potente"?

Para explicar é necessário ter em mente que:

CLOUD (a da Azure, no caso) === Ambiente super gerenciado/controlado

Se é um ambiente "super gerenciado" eu posso alugar uma máquina bem pequena, pagar mais barato por ela e ligar outra máquina somente quando o meu site tiver a demanda para isso.

Só para explicar o que quis dizer com "super gerenciado"... É pq, em ambientes como o da Azure, existem varias variáveis que podemos configurar conforme a nossa demanda. Podemos configurar largura de banda, espaço em disco, memória, etc. (várias outras coisas). E uma vez configurado podemos criar imagens (cópias da máquina) e replicar de maneira muito fácil. E ainda decidir que hora ligar/desligar cada máquina. E o melhor de tudo... Isso pode ser, depois de configurado (é claro :]), automatizado.

E com isso, as empresas, quando encontram a equação correta, passam a economizar dinheiro.

Resumindo... Cloud (Azure, no caso) é o lugar para que tenhamos um ambiente sempre com 100% de uso dos recursos. Ou seja, nada de ociosidade, nada de pagar pelo que não está sendo utilizado.